# Icinga (nagios) trend of query result

Tags: oracle, monitoring, nagios

I am setting up Icinga monitoring and after reading tons of documentation i still cant find out how to resolve the last aspect i need.

I need to execute a custom query on a Oracle datatabase on a extern network. The result of this query which will be a number (COUNT rows) I will have to save somehow in the Icinga database.

Then every 4 hours i want to execute a query that calculates the average of the results of query on the oracle database and have checks on these. Lets say if more then 50 then its critical if more then 40 then warning and so forth.

1. How can I set up an event that calls the Oracle database every 5 minutes and saves the result in the Icinga database?
2. How can I set up an event to read the information put in the database of Icinga? Suppose a query will suffice, i can calculate average with a query.

Thanks in advance! I love Icinga, but when things get complicated, it sometimes feels it comes short of solutions.

(Running on Ubuntu server,  Icinga2 and Icinga web)

Comment: Please ask icinga configuration questions on [sf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For icinga to query and store in the database use idoutils. COnfigure the required plugins for idodb which are modules of mysql. livestatus I think doesn't read or write in any database but is more prone to get live data and display it thats all.

Comment: a better way of thinking indeed

Answer (score 0):

I think so your solution is:

1. Use a plugin to run your query
2. Use mklivestatus. Livestatus has a similar query language to calculate a lot of things, AVG too. You can run it, the query livestatus system via script and maybe you can build a so simple script(bash,python,perl) to run your livestatus queries to calculate de AVG of your check sql results. Livestatus is easy to integrate with Icinga, it can to be another broker for you.

To see: https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html